# SQL Server Reporting Services connection issues

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I can connect to sql server reporting services both in the browser and through studio manager, but with problems.

In the browser, there's no "site sections" at the top or anything in the tab area (content, etc).

In Studio Manager, when I expand the "Home" node, I get the error
"Failed to retrieve data for this report.....The permissions granted to user '[computer name]\anonymous user]' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)...."

Os: Windows XP Professional
SQL Server 2005

Thank you.

Comment: This isn't programming related, it's server config - it belongs on ServerFault.com

Answer (score 0):

Your site admin has not granted you rights. Who is site admin?